# python lxml.html.soupparser.fromstring raising annoying warning

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

My code...

```
foo = fromstring(my_html)
```

it raises this warning...

```
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

To get rid of this warning, change this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "html.parser")

  markup_type=markup_type))
```

I have tried passing it the string `'html.parser'` but that does not work as it gives me an error saying that the string is not a callable so I tried `html.parser` and then I looked through the lxml module to see if I could find another parser, and couldn't. I looked through the python stdlib and saw that in 2.7 there is one called `HTMLParser` so I imported that and input the `beautifulsoup=HTMLParser` and that did not work either.

Where is the callable that I should be passing to `fromstring`?

EDIT added attempted solutions:

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
wiktionary_page = fromstring(wiktionary_page.read(), features="html.parser" )
```

and this

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import BeautifulSoup
wiktionary_page = fromstring(wiktionary_page.read(), beautifulsoup=lambda s: BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the *features* keyword which will set the parser.

```
tree = lxml.html.soupparser.fromstring("<p>foo</p>", features="html.parser" )
```

What happens in *fromstring* is *_parser* gets called but I think there is a bug in the line *bsargs['features'] = ['html.parser']*, it should be  `bsargs['features'] = 'html.parser'`:

```
def _parse(source, beautifulsoup, makeelement, **bsargs):
    if beautifulsoup is None:
        beautifulsoup = BeautifulSoup
    if hasattr(beautifulsoup, "HTML_ENTITIES"):  # bs3
        if 'convertEntities' not in bsargs:
            bsargs['convertEntities'] = 'html'
    if hasattr(beautifulsoup, "DEFAULT_BUILDER_FEATURES"):  # bs4
        if 'features' not in bsargs:
            bsargs['features'] = ['html.parser']  # use Python html parser
    tree = beautifulsoup(source, **bsargs)
    root = _convert_tree(tree, makeelement)
    # from ET: wrap the document in a html root element, if necessary
    if len(root) == 1 and root[0].tag == "html":
        return root[0]
    root.tag = "html"
    return root
```

You could also use a lambda:

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import BeautifulSoup
import lxml.html.soupparser

tree = lxml.html.soupparser.fromstring("<p>foo</p>", beautifulsoup=lambda s: BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser"))
```

Both suppress any warnings:

```
In [13]: from lxml.html import soupparser

In [14]: tree = soupparser.fromstring("<p>foo</p>", features="html.parser" )
In [15]: from lxml.html.soupparser import BeautifulSoup

In [16]: import lxml.html.soupparser


In [17]: tree = lxml.html.soupparser.fromstring("<p>foo</p>", beautifulsoup=lambda s: BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser"))
```

Comment: Both  work for me, are you using it exactly as posted?

Comment: I added what I tried, functionally identical to yours as far as I can tell

Comment: @deltaskelta, what version of lxml are you using, I cannot see how it is possible that you still see warning, in particular with the second example as there is no other call to bs4 bar the one inside the lambda

Comment: lxml 3.6 in python 2.7. I am running these commands in a django test environment, that is why the output is so annoying (clogs up my terminal so I cannot see test output clearly

Comment: @deltaskelta, well are you sure you don't have a stray call to BeautifulSoup where you have not passed a parser or missed on lxml call? It is simply not possible, definitely not with the last snippet as there is simply no call to the constructor after the lambda.

Comment: I don't know why the initial answer was not working for me, but I revisited the issues and this answer worked. Thanks